# scatter plot scale break function

Tags: r, plot, axis

I would like to create an auto-adjusting function introducing a break in x-axis.

Here is my dataset, already log transformed:

```
structure(list(log10 = c(1.62457434052758, 1.53152877697842, 
1.69833932853717, 1.59102517985612, 1.94931654676259, 1.84150479616307, 
1.50785971223022, 1.51459832134293, 1.50166067146283, 1.51618105515588, 
1.511396882494), log2 = c(25.4397183098679, 25.4060364200204, 
25.0540964465711, 24.9491581403185, 24.4560020696222, 23.6694432390975, 
10.5872019469992, 8.36608412759539, 7.9999573891952, 7.16653210552076, 
6.72718914855774)), .Names = c("log10", "log2"), row.names = c(578L, 
572L, 582L, 537L, 562L, 579L, 20L, 29L, 71L, 92L, 19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is how it looks when plotted:

```
plot(log10 ~ log2, df)
```

[image]

Conceptually similar solution has been explained here: https://joergsteinkamp.wordpress.com/2016/01/22/broken-axis-with-ggplot2/

but I would like it to auto-adjust to a given dataset. This way there is less problems with hidden data point making the approach less questionable.

Comment: it is not recommended to use breaks of axis.

Comment: why? i find it fair when all the points are included in the plot

Comment: your are cropping the data and blurring the scale. But if you have to try `plotrix::gap.plot(df$log2,df$log10, gap = c(11,21),gap.axis = "x")`

Comment: the point is not to crop the data, but introduce a break in the scale when where there is no data point, and make the script publicly available; see the above plots, how does a break between 15 and 20 (x-axis) affect the data?

Comment: but it could be that there is a datapoint. The reader can't know this.

Comment: that is the point of my question to make a function that would only crop then there is no data points